# firebase data not adding in array ionic 3

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

this is my ts file

```
import * as firebase from 'Firebase';
public items: Array<any> = [];

firebase.database().ref('favorite_locations/' + this.key).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

        this.items = [];
        snapshot.forEach( itemSnap => {
          this.items.push(itemSnap.val());
          return false;
        });
```

when i run the app every time display Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'items' of undefined

Comment: Try firebase.database().ref('favorite_locations/' + this.key).once('value').then((snapshot) => {}) - without the function()

Comment: @theriddle2 thank you it's working